# Traefik on EKS with CircuitBreaker

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, amazon-eks

I have deployed Traefik to eks.

I know that Traefik supports CircuitBreaker in general, but does it support in k8s?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Traefik supports Circuit Breaker in kubernetes.

The circuit breaker expression is provided using the `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/circuit-breaker-expression` annotation provided as part of the backend Service definition.

You cab find this information in [kubernetes docks](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.6/configuration/backends/kubernetes/)

Also you can inspect service example from [traefik user guide](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/).

Example of service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wensleydale
  annotations:
    traefik.backend.circuitbreaker: "NetworkErrorRatio() > 0.5"
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    targetPort: 80
    port: 80
  selector:
    app: cheese
    task: wensleydale
```